# How to use external letsEncrypt SSL certificate to my website on Azure vm

Tags: ssl, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have ASP.Net website hosted on one VM on MS Azure and connected to my website domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) on GoDaddy. I want to use letsencrypt certificate for my website. I have searched and found that I can use ssl certificate only with Web App on Azure, I have created web app and will use ssl certificate with, but still my vm url is linked with godaddy domain, hence how can I make requests coming to my website to go to my web app that is using ssl certificate, then redirect request to vm url or public IP ?

Answer (score -1):

You can install and configure the SSL certificate on your virtual machine (VM) in Azure directly if you're hosting an ASP.NET website there and would like to use an SSL certificate created with Let's Encrypt without using Azure App Service. The general steps to do this are as follows:

Obtain an SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt: To begin, get an SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt. To generate the certificate, you can use Certbot or any other ACME client. Ensure that the certificate files—fullchain.pem and privkey.pem, on average—are prepared.

1. Make sure your ASP.NET website is prepared to use SSL by making it
   secure. Modify your programme to listen on port 443 (HTTPS), then
   set up your web server (such as IIS) appropriately.
2. Move the privkey.pem and fullchain.pem Let's Encrypt certificate
   files to your virtual machine. To safely copy the data to your
   virtual machine, you can use programmes like SCP, SFTP, or secure
   copy.

You must install the SSL certificate on your virtual machine. Depending on the web server software you're using, the procedures for doing this may change. The following are some general IIS guidelines:

Start your virtual machine's IIS Manager.
Choose your website from the pane on the left.
Under "Edit Site," in the right pane, select "Bindings."
Create a new binding using port 443, the IP address, and Type: https.
Click on the "SSL certificate" dropdown menu and choose "Import."
See and pick the certificate files that you transferred to the virtual machine.

Comment: ok great, but will this help to make all users requests secure for my domain www.example.com hosted on Godaddy and linked to my vm public Ip and url ??

Comment: The steps I outlined in the previous response are focused on securing the communication between your Azure VM and the end-users.